# How could I improve this question?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

My [Which git commit this codebase is derived from?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40797400/308851)
 question was voted down and I do not understand why. The problem is real, today I needed it again. It's coming up repeatedly. It's not trivial. The question IMO is clear. So... why the downvotes and how to improve it?

Comment: I don't have an idea what your mess looks like, maybe add the output of the git log? I don't understand why finding the commit it started from is important. It started with the first commit, right? But I understand you're looking for a *different* commit. That comes from a tarball? What is in the tarball? A local git repo? How about adding some steps that *replicate* a demo-mess with commits and all the other git magic and then explain which commit you expect to find.

Comment: The very brief question is a screaming mismatch with the comment "My problem is much more difficult".  It is not an uncommon strategy, nobody can reasonably vote to close as a duplicate and any answers are nothing but wild guesses, so you get a smorgasbord of approaches to chose from.  Doesn't work, you get none to choose from.  Possibly the least constructive way to contribute to the Q+A here.

Comment: @HansPassant I added a clarification. Is this better now?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you checked '**Answer Your Own Question**' when you posted your question since there is an answer to that question posted by you at the exact same time the question was asked. This could have given the impression to many that you already knew the answer, but you are just providing the community with some knowledge on the issue.

Looking closer at your question, I don't see anything in it that warrants downvotes, as it's clear what you are asking, but it may be due to the answer you provided. The answer you gave looks like it's just providing additional information on what you've tried, in which case it should be appended to the question, and not given as an answer.

Like I said, I don't find anything wrong with the wording, I think it's clear what you are asking, and it's just finding the right people that know the answer. Consider adding a [bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty) to your question to increase its visibility.

Comment: What happened here is -- I was very happy I finally managed to cobble a solution together to a problem which reoccurs to me (and I suspected others) from time to time and wanted to share and I thought SO encourages sharing knowledge Q-A style.

Comment: @chx Absolutely! Knowledge Q&A style questions are of great benefit to the community, I was merely pointing out why some others may have believed the question to already have an acceptable answer.